# Serial e-mails from a table or database with either multiple datasets per e-mail adress or a multi-line cell with multiple URLS

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook, csv

I have the following, rather multi-faceted problem:

I have a list of data containing links I want to send to specific users using serial e-mail. There are multiple links for the same e-mail.

I currently have it as an excel sheet, where I used formulas to combine all data for a single e-mail adress into a single cell with multiple lines, eg:

e-mail              links
asdf@asdf.com       https://superuser.com/questions/ask1
                    https://superuser.com/questions/ask2
                    https://superuser.com/questions/ask3
                    https://superuser.com/questions/ask4
                    ...

Thus, I can use this excel sheet as a data source for a serial mail, using Word/Outlook (I found no way to do it with Thunderbird, since .csv does not really support multi-line fields...).

This works fine, but with one caveat:

My problem is, that even though my links are typed-out URLs, Outlook will not convert them into real hyperlinks when sending the e-mail. Thus, my users will get a list of links that are not really links but have to be copy/pasted into the browser. This obviously sucks.

I tried putting html into my data, but Outlook will just display the html and not interpret it

I tried using HYPERLINK function in excel, but I cannot have more than one hyperlink in a single cell

I tried converting my data into Access and using this as a data source, using two tables in Access, one for the data containing the hyperlinks and one for the e-mail adresses, and linked the two tables in Access. However, Word only allows me to select a single table from the Access database as a data source for serial e-Mail, so I end up with the same problem.

I'm open to any suggestions using any other software to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you mean you need to send the same links to different users using Mail Merge? If this is the case, you may try directly typing the hyperlinks in Word before sending out the messages. Or do you mean the links are different for different recipients?

Comment: I need to send different links to different users, and a rather big list. Manually typing anything is out of the question...